# Syntax issues for making a new variable from integer data

Tags: stata

I am currently trying to create my do-file for Australian data. The data input asked for a free-cell textbox participant postcode and I would like to create a new variable that assigns them to states. Stata has recognised the free-cell text as an "int" type, but when I try and make a new variable I get a syntax error. I have included the variations on the value range I have tried.

```
*Make postcode to states

generate famsur_state = "ACT/NSW" if famsur_postcode=="2000/2999"
replace famsur_state = "SA" if famsur_postcode==(5000/5999)
replace famsur_state = "QLD" if famsur_postcode==4000/4999
replace famsur_state = "NT" if famsur_postcode==">=0000 & <=0999"
replace famsur_state = "WA" if famsur_postcode==>=6000 & <=6999
replace famsur_state = "TAS" if famsur_postcode==>=7000 & <=7999
replace famsur_state = "VIC" if famsur_postcode==>=3000 & <=3999
label var famsur_state "Which state is the participant from?"
label define state  1   "ACT/NSW" ///
                    2   "SA" ///
                    3   "QLD" ///
                    4   "NT" ///
                    5   "WA" ///
                    6   "TAS" ///
                    7   "VIC" 

label values famsur_state state
```

Comment: In a thread you've deleted you got this advice: See detailed advice at stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info for how to show a data example. It still holds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand what you want to do here. If I understand you correctly, you're dealing with panel data of families within states, perhaps at one point in time, perhaps at many points in time. So we have a reference point, maybe tell me a bit more about the context the data are situated in.

Anyways, if this is true, and all you want to do is make a string variable based on the values of your numeric variables... Your issue here is that you've misspecified the variable type of the post code variable. More precisely, you've misspecified the way to delineate the range of codes you're interested in. At present, the way the code above is written, you want to generate the string ACT/NSW if the code is "2000/2999". Stata here is interpreting this as a string. This is to say that Stata would replace the variable with "ACT/NSW" if the contents of the cell were "2000/2999".

One way of tackling this problem is the inrange function. Obviously, it acts on variables only if the values of the variables fall within a given range. Here's my code so you can follow along. To see how it works, take away the comment of "set tr on" and you'll see it at work.

```
clear
cls

set obs 4
g famsur_postcode = .
replace famsur_postcode = 2000 in 1
replace famsur_postcode = 2999 in 2
replace famsur_postcode = 3000 in 3
replace famsur_postcode = 3999 in 4

loc states ACT/NSW VIC

loc ranges ""2000,2999" "3000,3999""

loc n: word count `states'

as `n' ==2

g famsur_state = ""
*set tr on
forv i = 1/`n' {
    
loc a: word `i' of `states' // Where 1 = "ACT/NSW" and 2 = "VIC"
loc b: word `i' of `ranges' // Where 1 = "2000,2999" and 2 = "3000,3999"

replace famsur_state = "`a'" if inrange(famsur_postcode,`b')
}

br
```

What I do above, is I make a macro for the state abbreviations and code ranges. I count how many words there are in each macro (in this case 2 but it can be any amount you like). I then loop over these as parallel lists (see the [good documentation](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/looping-over-parallel-lists/) on this on the Stata website). This, as you can see, seems to handle the first part correctly.

You also seem to want to assign value labels to these abbreviations. What I would do, is use the sencode command to accomplish this (`ssc inst sencode, replace`), and then recode the remaining variables by hand.

```
sencode famsur_state, replace
recode famsur_state (2=7)
```

Comment: There is no need to introduce local macros or loops. The OP's problem is a mapping from one variable to another. Perhaps something like `generate famsur_state = "ACT/NSW" if inrange(famsur_postcode, 2000, 2999)` will help.  If not, we need to know more about the OP's data. Whether the data are for families or are panel data is not of concern and `sencode` or `recode` don't seem needed at all.

Comment: I introduced the loop to generalize the solution, which we  both agree is the ```inrange``` function. The OP seems to have 7 states they are interested in. This means 7 lines of code. I prefer the loop because it is less error prone and can be generalized easier (what if there were 15 or 20 states?). If the OP were working with 2 states/groups, then I'd agree the loop is needlessly complex.

Comment: It's partly a matter of taste. I don't think a loop will make anything clearer or faster. The OP is clearly a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You have here three different guesses at the syntax, all wrong. P1 to P3 are identifiable problems with your syntax.

```
generate famsur_state = "ACT/NSW" if famsur_postcode=="2000/2999"
```

P1. This syntax is illegal and so wrong if the postcode variable is integer, as the double quotes imply that it is string,

```
replace famsur_state = "SA" if famsur_postcode==(5000/5999)
replace famsur_state = "QLD" if famsur_postcode==4000/4999
```

P2. This syntax is legal if the postcode is integer, but wrong because the slash indicates division, and the result of 5000/5999 and 4000/4999 is each case not an integer.

```
replace famsur_state = "NT" if famsur_postcode==">=0000 & <=0999"
```

P1. Again, the implication of string is illegal.

```
replace famsur_state = "WA" if famsur_postcode==>=6000 & <=6999
```

P3. You can say in Stata `>= 6000` to mean "greater than equal to 6000", but `&` does not work like that. `==>=` will not do what you want.

```
replace famsur_state = "TAS" if famsur_postcode==>=7000 & <=7999
```

P3. Similar comment.

```
label var famsur_state "Which state is the participant from?"
label define state  1   "ACT/NSW" ///
                    2   "SA" ///
                    3   "QLD" ///
                    4   "NT" ///
                    5   "WA" ///
                    6   "TAS" ///
                    7   "VIC"
```

This is legal and possibly even correct, meaning what you want:

```
generate famsur_state = "ACT/NSW" if inrange(famsur_postcode, 2000, 2999)
```

This would be legal too but Stata will ignore the leading zeros:

```
 replace famsur_state = "NT" if inrange(famsur_postcode, 0000, 0999)
```

If what you are seeing is the result of value labels, this could be quite wrong. It is possible that you have integers presenting as e.g. `0000` if the display format is `%04.0f`, but there is not enough hard information in the question to rule out other possibilities.

The functions `inrange()` will help you but otherwise Stata's syntax  here is what is documented at `help operators`.